# Mysql2 Error - using COALESCE, Unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails 4.1 Application, I'm building a query to find records in my collection (orders) by an attribute (name) of a polymorphic relationship (buyer). There are 2 possible tables for that polymorphic, so I'm using 2 LEFT JOINS + COALESCE to merge the attributes. Then attempting use the value from the COALESCE in a where clause.

The method in my ActiveRecord model looks like this:

```
class Order
  ...
  scope :join_by_buyer_name, -> { select("stock_orders.*", "COALESCE(core_customers.business_name, core_entities.name) AS buyer_name")
      .joins("LEFT JOIN core_customers ON stock_orders.buyer_id = core_customers.id AND stock_orders.buyer_type='Core::Customer'")
      .joins("LEFT JOIN core_entities ON stock_orders.buyer_id = core_entities.id AND stock_orders.buyer_type='Core::Entity'")
    }
  ...

  def find_by_buyer_name(term)
    all.join_by_buyer_name.where("buyer_name LIKE ?", term)
  end


end
```

When the ActiveRecord query is executed it looks like this

```
SELECT stock_orders.*, COALESCE(core_customers.business_name, core_entities.name) AS buyer_name
FROM `stock_orders`
LEFT JOIN core_customers ON stock_orders.buyer_id = core_customers.id AND stock_orders.buyer_type='Core::Customer'
LEFT JOIN core_entities ON stock_orders.buyer_id = core_entities.id AND stock_orders.buyer_type='Core::Entity'
WHERE `stock_orders`.`type` IN ('Stock::SalesOrder') AND (buyer_name LIKE "blah")
```

Until recently this worked, However I've started receiving the following error:

`Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'buyer_name' in 'where clause': SELECT stock_orders.*, COALESCE` etc etc etc

It works perfectly for sorting by the COALESCE value - ie `collection.order("buyer_name asc")` and up until recently the where query worked perfectly too...

I'm not sure what has changed and can't see anything in Rails or Mysql documentation. Can you see what's wrong here? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `ALIAS` in `WHERE` clause that is created from the `SELECT` clause. Use the computed column instead,

```
AND (COALESCE(core_customers.business_name, core_entities.name) LIKE "blah")
```

if you want to use the `ALIAS`, you have to wrap it in subquery like the query below,

```
SELECT *
FROM
     (
     SELECT stock_orders.*, 
           COALESCE(core_customers.business_name, core_entities.name) AS buyer_name
     FROM `stock_orders`
          LEFT JOIN core_customers 
                ON stock_orders.buyer_id = core_customers.id 
                     AND stock_orders.buyer_type='Core::Customer'
          LEFT JOIN core_entities 
                     ON stock_orders.buyer_id = core_entities.id 
                     AND stock_orders.buyer_type='Core::Entity'
     ) subquery
WHERE `type` IN ('Stock::SalesOrder') 
      AND (buyer_name LIKE "blah")
```